# Different input text style and submit button style in CSS

Tags: css, input

I used

```
#forms input {
    padding:0.15em;

    height:1.5em;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    background:#fafafa;
    font:bold 0.95em arial, sans-serif;
    -moz-border-radius:0.4em;
    -khtml-border-radius:0.4em;
}
```

but it produces the same style to both input text box and submit button. I want to give different style to submit button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have three options:

**1. A class**

Give the button a `class` attribute, and style that separately.

```
<input class="button">
```

You can address that using

```
 #forms input.button { ... }
```

**2. Use a different element**

use the `<button>` element:

```
<button>OK</button>
```

you can address that using

```
#forms button { ... }
```

**3. Selector**

use [the `type` selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors):

```
    #forms input[type="button"]  { ... }
```

however, that doesn't work in IE6.

I would go with the first or second one.

Comment: why not `#forms input.submitButton{/* css */}` where `submitButton` will be the class name for the button?

Comment: sorry your modified answer showed up only when I posted the comment.

Comment: If `button` can't be used for whatever reason, Modernizr can add support for `input[type='...']` selectors to IE6: http://www.modernizr.com/